# Prefill form:textarea spring mvc

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, modelattribute, spring-form

I've a `<form:textarea>` element. I would like to prefill it with data from the `modelAttributes`

Here's my code :

java :

```
ArrayList<Bloc> lblocs= new ArrayList<>();
lblocs = blocDao.getListBlocs();
modelMap.addAttributes("listeBlocs", lblocs);
```

Jsp :

```
    <form:form method="post" modelAttribute="listeBlocs">
        <c:forEach var="bloc" items="${listeBlocs}" varStatus="status">
            <form:textarea path="bloc_contenu" name="BContenu_textarea"
                 value="" />
        </c:forEach>
    </form:form>
```

bloc_contenu is supposed to be a String attribute to a Bloc object. When I load the page I get the following error :

`Invalid property 'bloc_contenu' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'bloc_contenu' is not readable or has an invalid getter method`

Any suggestions?

Comment: you should have bloc_contenu property on the commandBean of that form.

Answer (score 0):

change your textarea to this code

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="listeBlocs">
    <c:forEach var="listeBlocs" items="${listeBlocs}" varStatus="status">
        <form:textarea path="bloc_contenu" name="BContenu_textarea">
            ${listeBlocs.columnName} 
        </form:textarea>
    </c:forEach>
</form:form>`
```

columnName is the name of the column in your database. you must have created it in model class with its getterts/setters!